# Hydrogen bond of ozone

Tags: hydrogen-bond

Why can't $\ce{O3}$ form hydrogen bonds with water? It has lone pairs of electrons. I do not know the answer.

Comment: It can.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Sorry I meant O2

Comment: It can as well.

Comment: Then edit question with what you really want

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, I would predict it does form H-bonds with water. Please provide an authoritative (scholarly) reference claiming it doesn't. The only information I found on the web was the claim that it decomposes *slower* in water than in the gaseous state. To me, this *implies* H-bonding is occurring.